MariaDB Galera and Geo redundancy
I am trying to simulate 2 clusters in different datacenters/different locations, using VMWare VSXi and 6 VMs: 3 are located on DC1 and other 3 on DC2. All nodes are RHEL 9.
Both DCs communicate through the same VLAN and this works fine.
I have installed MariaDB 10.5.22 + Galera.
On DC1 , the 3 nodes are all data nodes, where node #1 was bootstrapped using galera_new_cluster script
On DC2, 2 nodes are Data nodes and I added 1 Arbitrator
When starting nodes, all 6 are connected on the same cluster, sharing data, and this seems to be working fine.
The problem that I find is when I simulate a network outage: I modify VLAN ID on DC2 and both DCs loose connectivity.
Looking at each node's logs, they effectively loose connectivity, but :

all nodes (3 from DC1 and 2 from DC2) are unavailable for queries
Arbitrator keeps retrying to connect to nodes, ex.:
Oct  7 20:08:16 ire-lab-se3 garb-systemd[8999]: 2024-10-07 20:08:16.562  INFO: (dd79df53-972e, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 00000000-0000 with addr tcp://10.20.0.1:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S, socket stats: rtt: 0 rttvar: 250000 rto: 4000000 lost: 1 last_data_recv: 358971429 cwnd: 1 last_queued_since: 359271583299206 last_delivered_since: 359271583299206 send_queue_length: 0 send_queue_bytes: 0

I was expecting that:

DC1 would remain available and synced, after all, the bootstrap was on Node#1 and there are 3 nodes available on this network
Garbd arbitrator would handle the remaining 2 nodes in DC2, allowing applications on DC2 to use the current data

I have tried multiple test scenarios, and this is the only one that is failing (network outage) and I can't seem to be able to solve the issue.
The configuration files on each Galera Data Node is similar to (only node name and ID differ):
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]
log_error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.err
log_warnings=9
#default_time_zone='UTC'
table_definition_cache=4096
table_open_cache=4096
#innodb_read_only_compressed=OFF # only for 10.6 and later

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld/mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

# disabling symlinks is recommend to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic_links=0

#enable binary logging
log_bin=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb-bin.index

#enable relay log files
relay_log=/var/log/mariadb/relay-bin
relay_log_index=/var/log/mariadb/relay-bin.index

log_slave_updates=1
performance_schema=ON
interactive_timeout=180
wait_timeout=180

max_connections=500

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.5 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.5]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
wsrep_on=ON
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
# below parameter should not include Arbitrators, only MariaDB nodes
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.20.0.1,10.20.0.2,10.20.0.3,10.20.0.4,10.20.0.5"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster_LAB'
wsrep_node_address='10.20.0.1'
wsrep_node_name='galera_LAB_1'
wsrep_sst_method='rsync'
#'mariabackup'
#wsrep_sst_auth=backupuser;backupuser
server_id=2
wsrep_provider_options='gmcast.segment=1;gcache.size=2G'
#wsrep_sst_donor="galera_1"

and the Gardb Arbitrator is set as:
# Copyright (C) 2012 Codership Oy
# This config file is to be sourced by garb service script.

# A comma-separated list of node addresses (address[:port]) in the cluster
 GALERA_NODES="10.20.0.4:4567 10.20.0.5:4567"

# Galera cluster name, should be the same as on the rest of the nodes.
 GALERA_GROUP="galera_cluster_LAB"

# Optional Galera internal options string (e.g. SSL settings)
# see https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/galera-parameters.html
 GALERA_OPTIONS=""

# Log file for garbd. Optional, by default logs to syslog
# FOR SOME REASON IT DOESN'T WORK; RETURNS AN ERROR PRBABLY RELATED TO PERMISSIONS
# LOG_FILE="/var/log/mariadb/garbd.log"

# Where to persist necessary data
# WORK_DIR=""

So I think this is pretty much standard....
I googled a lot, but could not find anything that makes this work as expected. The requirements are that, in production, both DCs should communicate freely and if a network outage happens, application servers on both DCs should continue working with the local mariadb galera nodes (querying and inserting new rows, if required) and once the network is up again, all nodes should sync data between each of them (new data from DC1 exported to DC2 and new data from DC2 exported to DC1, and so on....)
Am I missing something here? could anyone help?
Thanks
Sergio

"simulate a network outage: I modify VLAN ID on DC2 and both DCs loose connectivity" -- Not enough info about how you simulated the outage.  Keep in mind that Galera can withstand a single point of failure, and not necessarily multiple failures.

Hi Rick, we simulate by modifying the VLAN ID. Resuming, DC1 is on a VLAN ID 4093 and DC2 is also on the same VLAN. To simulate a network outage, I modify the VLAN of the DC2 to 4094 (for ex.). As different VLANs do not communicate with each other, this results in communication failure between the DC1 and DC2, similar to a network outage between 2 datacenters. Additional details: when I manually shutdown all nodes from DC2 (the 2 data nodes + the arbitrator), DC1 stays up and available, just like expected.

Sounds like a variant on "split-brain" (Primary-Primary).  In that case, all clients need to switch to using one of the clusters.  But, without further info, the system cannot safely know which datacenter to failover.

If I understand this correctly, you have 6 nodes. 3 in DC1 (3 data nodes) and 3 in DC2 (2 data and 1 arbiter). All are connected together forming a 6 node cluster. If that assumption is correct, the cluster behaves as expected. Galera requires a majority of the cluster to be available in order to operate. In the case of 6 nodes, that would have to be 4 nodes (4 data or 3 data + 1 garbd) to be connected. If you have 3 and 3, while cutting the network in between, you have exactly 50% - 50% split and both partitioned parts will switch to non-Primary. There’s no other way in this scenario.
The solution for an automated failure handling is to have 3DC. Then you can build topology like:
DC1: 3 data nodes, DC2: 3 data nodes, DC3 1 garbd (arbitrator) node. It that case, if there’s a failure of a single datacenter, at the minimum you have 4 out of 7 nodes, keeping it a majority. In that case 4 nodes will stay in Primary state, serving the traffic.
EDIT/ADDITION/CLARIFICATION
I think you are missing the point as to why bootstrapping the cluster in DC2 does not make any sense. Let’s take a look at it step by step visually.

This is a normal scenario - transactions are written to both DC1 and DC2 and are distributed across all nodes in the cluster. Every node will have transactions T1, T2, T3, Z1, Z2 and Z3.

Now, let’s say you don’t have a connection between DC1 and DC2. If you bootstrap DC2, you have a separate 2 node cluster there. You can execute writes which otherwise would not be possible. So, we have transactions T11, T22 and T33 in DC1 and Z11, Z22 and Z33 in DC2

There is no syncing of data, those are two separate entities. Cluster in DC1 stores transactions T11, T22 and T33. Cluster in DC2 stores transactions Z11, Z22 and Z33.
Now, if you want to resync DC2 with DC1 what will happen?

Data on nodes in DC2 will be removed and data from donor in DC1 will be transferred.

As a result, transactions Z11, Z22 and Z33 are gone forever, all nodes only have T11, T22 and T33. As you can imagine, this is bad. In this scenario it does not make any sense to even use DC2 as whatever you’ll write there will be gone anyway. You can as well stick to just a single datacenter.
The whole point of having 3 DC is that if DC1 is unavailable, it goes non-Primary and you do not touch that. It does not accept writes. Other datacenters do. Your application can still work based on the remaining datacenters. It can read the data, it can write the data. Once the DC1 becomes available again, it gets synced from other nodes, which were receiving traffic. As DC1 was not writeable, you don’t have to worry that some data will be lost - if you could not write to DC1, you can’t loose anything on SST. You do not have to touch anything, you only have to configure your application (or load balancer) to track the status of the nodes and if node does not respond or respond that it is in non-Primary state, you just connect to another node that’s available. In the case of 3DC, as long as nodes in DC2 and DC3 are up and running, there will always be nodes available to write to.

Thanks @Severalnines! I will test that solution (3+3+1). Also, is having 3 data nodes in DC1 + 2 data nodes in DC2 without arbitrator, would it be a good solution even upon a network outage? Would DC1 and DC2 keep receiving queries locally and then be able to resync once both DCs get connected?

I also tested network outage and run SET GLOBAL wsrep_provider_options='pc.bootstrap=YES'; on DC2 so nodes could be queried.But once I got the connectivity between back,the nodes could not resync.Is there a method to force resync?I had to delete data folders in DC2 and restart Mariadb on DC2 nodes...

Meanwhile, I tested the 3 datacenters solution where 3 data nodes are set on DC1 and other 3 data nodes on DC2 and a arbitrator on DC3. both DC1 and DC2 communicate with DC3, as well as DC1 communicates with DC3. When disconnecting DC2 from DC1, but keeping connection with DC3, so comms are DC1->DC3 and DC2->DC3. In this scenario, I get this error "ERROR 1047 (08S01): WSREP has not yet prepared node for application use" on all nodes. I would expect that DC1 and DC2 would continue working independently, using Garbd... Am I missing something?

@scharrua
Having 3 nodes in DC1 and 2 nodes in DC2 will not allow for safe handling of the failures. In this case DC1 will always have the majority of the nodes so it will always be in the Primary state. On the other hand, DC2 will always be in non-Primary as soon as you cut off the network. As you have noticed, bootstrapping nodes in DC2 does not help to solve a problem. Bootstrapping means creating a new cluster. Afterwards you have, technically, two separate clusters - one in DC1, old, and one new in DC2. .........

@scharrua
They cannot be joined, you have to resync nodes from one of the DC, just like you did with nodes from DC2 - remove data, restart, let them sync.
As for the 3 DC solution, without MySQL logs that contain info about what happened we cannot tell anything here. In general, it should work. Why it did not, the answer is in the log files where Galera writes, typically quite generously, how the cluster state changed, how does the connectivity between nodes looked like and so on.

@scharrua Make sure that you analyse logs from all the nodes in the cluster as they may have different point of view on the situation in the cluster.

"@scharrua They cannot be joined, you have to resync nodes from one of the DC, just like you did with nodes from DC2 - remove data, restart, let them sync" Thanks for the tip! So, how can I make DC2 be available for query upon network outage between DCs and rejoin DC1 Primary cluster automatically?

@scharrua
The only way is the 3rd DC along with the same number of nodes in DC1 and DC2. So, 2 + 2 + 1 or 3 + 3 + 1. This is the scenario in which there will always be a majority of one of the datacenter would go down or lost network connection and therefore cluster will maintain Primary state.
Having said that, you mentioned you had some problems with that setup. If it is still the case, you probably want to look into the log files of all nodes to see what’s causing the cluster to go non-Primary....

@scharrua
Make sure that the connectivity is in place between all of the nodes across all of the datacenters before you start running tests and cut off one DC from the network.

I ended up in installing 3 data nodes on DC1 and 2 data nodes on DC2,having the 5 nodes on the same cluster.When there is a network outage between datacenter's,the 3 data nodes on DC1 will remain working correctly.However, on DC2, the 2 remaining nodes will not accept queries,as expected.To solve this,I created a script that checks connectivity between DCs and if there is an outage it will set pc.boostrap=yes on DC2,creating a 2 nodes cluster.Once outage is solved,I stop the 2 nodes,set seqno=-1 in grastate.dat and restart service,rejoining DC1!Wondering if i need a Garb?? Any thoughts?

@scharrua, I think you are missing the point why you should not bootstrap the “failed” part of the cluster. Let’s look at it step by step.


5 nodes in the cluster. All writes are stored in all of them, replicated by Galera


There’s a network outage


a. DC1 has 3 nodes, it continues to be in Primary state
b. DC2 has 2 nodes, it switches to non-Primary state.
Why this is intended situation? Nodes in DC2 do not accept writes - only writes are allowed in DC1. This is because DC2, when it will rejoin the cluster, it will sync its data from DC1...

Now, if you will:

Bring back DC2 through bootstrapping

a. DC1 can accept writes, transactions t1, t2, t3 have been executed
b. DC2 can accept writes, transactions z1 and z2 have been executed

You want DC2 to rejoin the cluster - what would happen with the z1 and z2? Those transactions will be removed.

As you can see, there’s no way to sync the DC1 and DC2 other than manually moving the transactions. For automated resync, any writes that will happen on DC2 (or DC1, depending on which cluster you will be joining nodes to) will have to be removed.

This is even worse than not having the option to write. If you cannot write (as in the “correct” scenario), that’s just it - errors in the application. If you can write, app will behave as expected but then some data that user entered (orders, transactions, new blog posts, articles added to the ecommerce etc) will just disappear.

I understand what you mean, but actually, client applications will only write to DC1 (on nodes t1, t2 or t3). So I thought that, when having a network outage between DCs, by making DC2 a stand alone cluster for client applications located on DC2 to read (client applications on DC2 will not write data), there would not be an issue. With these new details in mind, is this not a correct solution? I know that once the outage is solved, z1 and z2 need to be stopped, gradstate.dat modified seqno, and then restart z1 and z2 to rejoin the cluster. Also, this is for a routing application for a telco.

Would adding a 3rd not to DC2 (z3) help in any way?

Hey @scharrua, I think you are still missing the point as to why bootstrapping the cluster in DC2 does not make any sense. I edited our answer and added visual representation of each step. Please check it out.
I hope this meets you well.

Thanks @Severalnines! The reason why we need DC2 data nodes available upon network outage is to have SIP servers in DC2 processing calls, even with the current routes available on DC2 (they may be some versions behind DC1's routes, that is not an issue for us). Even if DC2 is not connected to DC1, SIP servers need to process calls, so this requires querying DB in DC2, and the only way I know is to bootstrap DC2 data nodes. SIP servers are not meant to write data on DB, so there won't be transactions in DC2 DB. Hope this clarifies a bit more.
